# ListView how to select the text inside a cell?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

well i have worked with datagridview now i need to work with a listview i dont know how to select the value it has in one cell..

my another option is when a cell was added or deleted, all this information is on datagridview
but it doesn't have a (datasourcechanged) then how can i anyone of these?

I tried secund with this code:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = lvDevices
```

so i could select anyone but i need when in datagrid changed its value, it passed to datagridview well my another way is
how can i select the value of one cell in a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this in this  listview1_doubleclick event. ...

```
string a = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[column index corresponding selected cell].Text.
```